# body background and height

Tags: css

When I try to set a background image on the body element and the page is heigher than the viewport and you are able to scroll up or down.. Then the background image starts/ends at the position where the viewport ends when scrollTop is 0..

Its like body height 100% is equal to the viewport height? Why? What am I doing wrong?

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    background:url('/new/gfx/layout.bottom_bg.png') bottom repeat-x #eef7ff;
    margin:0px;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong; 100% height for the body *does* mean the height of the viewport.  If you want it to be the height of the image, you should use the pixel height of the image.  If you want it to expand to the size of the content, you can use the `min-height` property (set to 100%).

Comment: but what can you do to solve it and make the `bottom` work in the background property?

Comment: You will most likely want to use `min-height`, to allow it to stretch if needed, but take up at least the whole viewport.  When it stretches and you scroll, you should see it at the bottom.

If, on the other hand, you want it fixed at the bottom of the viewport, regardless of scrolling the content, you can use `background-attachment: fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

`height:100%` IS equal to the viewport height. Either dont specify a height or use `min-height: 100%;`