# Overriding background (height + color ) property in HTML

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am encountering a strange issue in my app where I have applied a class to body which sets its background to gray. Now recently while doing some other changes, this issue cropped up.

In current scenario, the part of body that's loaded on the initial load in the viewport has gray background, but when I scroll the page down, the rest of the body has white background.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7640823/1242321) answer rightly mentioned that

> height:100% IS equal to the viewport height. Either dont specify a
>   height or use min-height: 100%;

Now, I recently included angular-material styles in the app which has the body tag as:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}
```

I am not sure how to undo this styling while using angular-material, as in, what should be the right value I should be giving to height to fix this issue. I tried removing this 100% height manually, the issue gets resolved, but I would not want to edit the third party file manually, rather override the styling in my app. I tried using the basic solution of giving body styling in my css as below, but it does not override the angular-material styles.

```
body {
    background-color: #edecec !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this are appreciated.

Comment: You could try adding `body{height:auto;min-height:100%;}` see if that helps.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for the inputs. I was already using min-height:100%; earlier while the issue occurred. I just tried height:auto, but it even shortened the background than the viewport with white background showing up as soon the content ends. So I think that is height:auto is not the right way to fix it.

Comment: Can you tell me if there is any issue in this demo? https://jsfiddle.net/d16ub8mx/ as far as see the silver background expands correctly.